# Local machine env vars not passed to vscode dev container

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-compose

**Problem:**

When I spin up a vscode dev container that uses a docker compose file, the desired env vars set within my local machine are not passed to the dev container even though the associated docker-compose.yml and devcontainer.json files are allowing the local env vars to be passed.

Here are the relevant files:

`devcontainer.json`

```
{
  "remoteEnv": {
      "MYVAR": "${localEnv:MYVAR}"
  },
  "containerEnv": {
    "MYVAR": "${localEnv:MYVAR}"
  },
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux#": "/bin/bash",
        "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
        "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/autopep8",
        "python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/black",
        "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/yapf",
        "python.linting.banditPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/bandit",
        "python.linting.enabled": true,
        "python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/flake8",
        "python.linting.mypyPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/mypy",
        "python.linting.pycodestylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pycodestyle",
        "python.linting.pydocstylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pydocstyle",
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pylint"
      }
    }
  },
  "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
  "features": {
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-from-docker:1": {
      "version": "latest"
    },
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/github-cli:1": {
      "version": "latest"
    }
  },
  "name": "Development",
  "service": "dev",
  "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace"
}
```

`docker-compose.yml`

There are other services within the docker-compose.yml file but for the sake of simplicity, they have been removed.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dev:
    image: python:3.9-slim-buster
    container_name: dev
    volumes:
    - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - ../:/workspace
    entrypoint: [/bin/bash, ./.devcontainer/entrypoint.sh]
    command: sleep infinity
    environment:
    - MYVAR=${MYVAR}
    networks:
      custom_network:

networks:
  custom_network:
    name: custom_network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

`entrypoint.sh`

(contains only relevant code)

```
#!/bin/bash

exec "$@"
```

**Steps**

1. export env var to local machine via vscode terminal: `export MYVAR=foo`
2. Run the vscode extension: `Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Container`
3. Within dev container shell, `echo $MYVAR` results are empty

**Attempts:**

1. Remove `remoteEnv` and `containerEnv` from devcontainer.json - same results
2. Check Terminal > Integrated: Inherit Env is checked as mentioned on vscode [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/environment-variables)
3. Remove the stopped dev container from the previous attempt before performing the steps mentioned above - same results